# Platform credentials are invalid APNS certificate upload in AWS

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns

I have created a p12 certificate and and uploaded it on amazon web services for SNS. But I got an error while uploading the p12 certificate.

> Attributes Reason: Platform credentials are invalid
>       Invalid parameter: Attributes Reason: Platform credentials are invalid (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameter; Request ID: b21aabb6-2f37-5c44-99ea-9569c2504314)

Comment: Just make your `.p12` file without selecting the key. Import only certificate.

Answer (score 0):

For APNS, Amazon SNS differentiates between the production (APNS) and development (APNS_SANDBOX) versions of APNS.

Recheck ur credentials and APNS_SANDBOX version.

Comment: Did you know about "PlatformApplicationDisabled"?. I got this error in server. so trying to reuplaod the certificate on server.

Comment: This usually means you upload the wrong certificate. Please revisit the developer guide http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-apns.html